# Paypal - Custom Logo Appears on Checkout Page But Not on Cart Page

Tags: paypal

whether i add the 150x50 image via externally hosted https or upload to the profile image in Paypal, it will not show up on the 'cart' page, but it will on the 'checkout' page.

i believe we're simply using the Paypal Website Standard Payment method by creating "buy now" buttons via their button creator tool, then just inserting the given html in to our webpage.

when the user clicks on one of these buttons, it opens a Paypal shopping cart page in a new window/tab. where the logo should go, it just says "Your shopping cart". then when clicking on the checkout button (for either to login & use paypal or to not login & use creditcards) the following pages does have the logo.

note: the cart/checkout system is NOT using either the "classic" nor "enhanced" templates that we could customize. it's using a non-customizable "advanced" view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI - i heard from Paypal Tek Support and they said this is the intended behaviour. logos will not appear on the cart page but will appear on the checkout page.

ref: https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/PayPal-Payments-Standard/Custom-Logo-amp-Cart-Style-Confusion/m-p/1571415#M2047